# Smart way to compress iterated integrals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

If you have a triple- integral

$$\int_0^a \int_0^b \int_0^c f(b,c,x) dx dc db$$

can you also rewrite this somehow in a more condensed form with only one integral over a certain set?

Comment: I only know Cauchy's theorem , which says that it does not matter in which order you evaluate the integrals. So you can first integrate wrt the variable which has the least messy terms and go from there since we know that integration usually makes the terms messier.

Comment: There is a problem with your integral: you cannot have a function that depends on variable $a$, with bounds that also depend on $a$. Same with $b$. Maybe you meant $f(x,y,z)$ ?

Comment: @Kuifje Surely you can. What's the problem with $\int_0^a f(a,x)dx$?

Comment: sorry, it was indeed a typo. and of course you cannot exchange the order of integration, as the integrals depend on each other, as user "Avi" indicated.

Comment: Nevermind, you are correct, my reading was too hasty. It is possible, but is that really what the OP meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the possibility that the OP may have messed up the variables, let me try evaluate this integral as is:

$$ \int_0^b \int_0^c f(a,b,x)dxdc=\int_0^b \int_x^b f(a,b,x)dcdx=\int_0^b (b-x)f(a,b,x)dx, $$

so the original integral is

$$ \int_0^a \int_0^b (b-x)f(a,b,x)dx db=\int_{\{(x,b):0\le x\le b\le a\}} (b-x)f(a,b,x)dS, $$

so this is a two-dimensional integral over a triangle.

OK, so now the integral is

$$ \int_0^a \int_0^b \int_0^c f(b,c,x)dxdcdb=\int_{\{(x,c,b):0\le x\le c\le b\le a\}} f(b,c,x)dV$$.

It is a three-dimensional integral over a pyramid.

Comment: sorry, I messed it up indeed. can you still generalize your approach?